# WildFly Access control list behind proxy/load-balancer

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I am using one Wildfly based application. I have deployed application inside docker and accessing it through AWS load-balancer. Also, I have enabled "**proxy-address-forwarding=true**" in standalone.xml with ip based filter for path as -

`<expression-filter name="ipAccess" expression="path-prefix('/auth/admin') -> ip-access-control(default-allow=false, acl={'127.0.0.1/32 allow', '172.17.0.0/16 allow', '192.168.0.0/16 allow' })"/>`

But whenever I am trying to access application, I am getting **403 Access Denied.** Filtering works fine for me if I removed **"proxy-address-forwading=true"** from standalone.xml